# Facebook Share Dialog Not in Pop-ups

Tags: facebook, html, popup, opera

So, I'm developing a new application for Opera TV and need a help. Is there a way to use the Facebook Share Dialog without Popups? (Since the Opera TV navigator won't open Popups). I tried iframes, but I wasn't concerned about security restrictions.

Thanks in advance,

João Bruno

P.S.: I don't want to redirect my user to another page, since my app is an online radio. I just want my user to share what he is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT
Based on CBroe's comment below, just try redirecting to a link such as

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20app_id=145634995501895%20&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption%20&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F%20&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

//ignore below
The dialogs should have a "display" parameter that you can customise.
It defaults to popup

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

specifically look at the parameters here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#params

Comment: The display parameter only influences how Facebook _formats_ its dialogs – less UI for smaller popup windows, full UI for full page. It has _nothing_ to do with how that dialog is opened.

Comment: Ok, I got it.. I forgot to say, I don't want to redirect my user to another page, since it's an online radio. I just want hi to share what he is listening to.